# Expected value larger than conditional expected value

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $X \subseteq \Omega$ and $Y \subseteq \Omega$ be two sets with $X \cap Y = \emptyset$ and $\mathbb{P}(X) > 5 \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y)$.

Given a set of $n$ randomly chosen elements of the sample space $\Omega$: $S = \{e_1, \ldots e_n\}$.

We use the notation $h_X(S)$ for the number of observations of an element $e$ with $e \in X$. More clearly:
$$
h_X(S) := \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{e_i \in X}
$$
where $1_{e_i \in X}$ is the indicator function, which is $1$ if $e_i \in X$ and $0$ otherwise.

I am sure that the following claim is true:
$$
E[h_X(S)] \geq E[h_Y(S) - h_X(S) \mid h_Y(S) \geq h_X(S)]
$$

Is this true? And how can I prove it?

Comment: There's smth. strange. For every $e \in \Omega$ we have either $e \in X$ or $e \notin X$. Thus $P(e \in X)$ is $0$ or $1$. Moreover $P(e \in Y)$ is $0$ or $1$. If $P(e \in X) > P(e \in Y)$ then $P(e \in X) = 1$ and $P(e \in Y)=0$.

Comment: I wanted to say: For a randomly chosen element $e \in \Omega$ it is more likely that the element comes from $X$ than from $Y$.

Comment: For example, I have a urn problem with 6 blue balls and 1 red ball. Then for a randomly chosen ball $\mathbb{P}[\text{ball is blue}] > 5 \cdot \mathbb{P}[\text{ball is red}]$. So maybe better say $\vert X \vert > 5 \cdot \vert Y \vert$?

Comment: Set $n=1$ and $X \cup Y = \Omega$, with both $X$ and $Y$ non empty. The right hand side of your inequality is 1, while the left hand side is smaller than 1.

Comment: @nicola I edited your question a bit. Do you suppose that $\Omega$ is finite or at least countable?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I suppose $\Omega$ is finite.

Comment: Is my claim true, if we assume $X \cup Y \neq \Omega$ (maybe and $n > 1$)?

Comment: No, it's not. Suppose you have one million X balls, 100k Y balls and just one (or two, for that matters) "neutral" balls. Calculate your lhs and rhs in these scenario.